# Is it possible to download Visual Studio 2010 Updates?

Tags: download, windows-update, visual-studio-2010, automatic-update, file-download

When we change Windows we have to download all Visual Studio 2010 updates with Windows Updater and install them again.
Is it possible to download Visual Studio 2010 Updates in an installing pack ?

Comment: Yes. When they show up in windows update, carefully analyze the screen. You'll have option like find out more about this update. When you click on it, you'll go to the update's site from which you can download it.

Comment: Well, How can we download all Updates in an installing pack !!! Is it possible ?

Comment: I think that microsoft doesn't provide such an option. There may be other programs that can download updates and provide packages which could be easier to install, but I can't recommend anything right now as haven't used one in very long time.

Comment: Service pack 1 is available for direct download [here](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=210710).

Comment: I've installed it but there are some updates after it, I wanna download all update till today in an installing pack

Comment: There is no such thing, other than service packs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, We can't do it at all to download all of VS2010 updates in an installing pack.

Comment: It is possible, just download them manually from Microsoft.

Answer (score 0):

Some updates are only available via WindowsUpdate but after installing Visual Studio you can use the [Web Platform installer](http://www.microsoft.com/web/downloads/platform.aspx) to select and install any other package (SP1, MVC3, Windows Phone 7, Silverlight). All packages will then be downloaded and installed at once.

Comment: What about Security Updates ?

Comment: Security Updates are provided by WindowsUpdate.

Answer (score 0):

I am not exactly sure what you mean with download in an installing pack, but if you want just the executable from Microsoft update you can try the command line tools [WuInstall](http://www.wuinstall.com) with the option

```
wuinstall /download_to <my_directory>
```

it should download you the install executables for the updates.

If you just want save updates by saving bandwidth see also the [caching feature](http://www.wuinstall.com/index.php/en/pro/40-news/48-cache) of WuInstall.

Answer (score -1):

you can download New version Microsoft visual studio Community 2015

http://www.cairo-pro.com/2016/08/download-microsoft-visual-studio-Community-offline-iso-Developers.html

Comment: Why is the link you provided an unofficial link instead of directly from Microsoft?  Please consider updating your link to be directly from Microsoft.  The website you link to is extremely shady.